# scipy curve_fit does not consume custom functions

Tags: scipy, curve-fitting

I defined the fit method as follows:

```
def fit(f1, f2, x_data, y_data):
    def fun(x, w1, w2):
        return w1*f1(x) + w2*f2(x)
    return curve_fit(fun, x_data, y_data)
```

then this piece of code works fine:

```
x_data, y_data = np.array(range(0, 5)), np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 2])

f1 = np.sin
f2 = np.cos

fit(f1, f2, x_data, y_data)
```

however, the following code produces: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

```
d1 = {0: 1, 1:3, 2:4, 3:5, 4:3}
d2 = {0: 2, 1:1, 2:6, 3:2, 4:1}

f1 = lambda x: d1.get(x)
f2 = lambda x: d1.get(x)

fit(f1, f2, x_data, y_data)
```

Is there any way around? Or, are there any other options to do linear combination fit of custom functions to the given data?

Comment: I believe the issue is that your functions produce `None` for all values that are not keys. What is your goal that you want to use a dictionary instead of a function?

Comment: f1 = np.frompyfunc(lambda x: d1.get(x), 1, 1)
f2 = np.frompyfunc(lambda x: d1.get(x), 1, 1)
produces another error. It might really be caused by the fact, that these are discrete functions. But why there's problem with that?

Comment: My intention is to make fit of a linear combination of discrete functions to a data sample. The weights in front of each discrete function in the linear combination would parameters of fit.

Comment: A `dict.get` does not work with arrays (or lists)

Answer (score 1):

You need to vectorize your functions to allow them to work on numpy arrays:

```py
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def fit(f1, f2, x_data, y_data):
    def fun(x, w1, w2):
        return w1*f1(x) + w2*f2(x)
    return curve_fit(fun, x_data, y_data)

x_data, y_data = np.array(range(0, 5)), np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 2])

d1 = {0: 1, 1:3, 2:4, 3:5, 4:3}
d2 = {0: 2, 1:1, 2:6, 3:2, 4:1}

f1 = np.vectorize(d1.get)
f2 = np.vectorize(d2.get)

fit(f1, f2, x_data, y_data)
```

Comment: very cool. I did try to transform the functions so that they are not discreet and use the np.frompyfunc, but that really did not help. The np.vectorize did the job.

Comment: Glad it helps, note that vectorize does not bring any speedup (or almost), it's pretty much running a for loop on (homogeneous and memory contiguous) input.

Comment: + please validate the answer if it solves your issue =)